# Push items into empty State array of objects

Tags: javascript, arrays, reactjs, react-state-management

I am trying to push new items into `State array` of `objects`, facing some problem. Below is my code. I am sure I am going something wrong

```
constructor(props) {
  super(props);
  this.state = {
    bill: []
  };
}

componentWillReceiveProps(nextProps, nextState) {
  if (nextProps.bills !== this.props.bills) {
    let billsObj = nextProps.bills
    billsObj.map((billsObj) => {
      var joined = this.state.bill.concat({billId:billsObj.id,checked:false});
      console.log(joined, "joined", this.state.bill)
      this.setState({
        bill: [...this.state.bill, ...joined]
      }, () => {
        console.log(this.state.bill, billsObj.id)
      })
    })
  }
}
```

In `componentWillReceiverProps` I am getting the `array` and then mapping it to push values into `state` `array`,  But in the end I am only getting a single value in the array , but `props array` has 11 values and I am only getting single value in my `state array`. Hope to get some help.

Comment: Do you really need to put the `bills` from your props in state? Can't you just use them from the props in render instead?

Comment: I need to put because I need that state array, actually I want to make an array of objects, I am just updating my question

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to account for previous state if you are updating a piece of state that is derived from the current state, which is explained in detail [here](https://reactjs.org/docs/state-and-lifecycle.html#state-updates-may-be-asynchronous). This is why your multiple calls to `setState` just end up with the last `bill` in your state array.

It will work as expected if you keep your `bills` in an intermediary array, and just `setState` once when you are done:

```
componentWillReceiveProps(nextProps, nextState) {
  if (nextProps.bills !== this.props.bills) {
    const bill = nextProps.bills.map(bill => {
      return { billId: bill.id, checked: false };
    });

    this.setState({ bill });
  }
}
```